# PathForResource with wildcard for thefilename parameter

Tags: ios, swift

I know this sounds weird, but is it possible to use wildcard for theFileName parameter?

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(theFileName, ofType: "csv", inDirectory: directory)
```

Because I have several files that follow particular naming scheme. Basically, the first part of the filename is English and the second part is French. They are separated by three dashes. For example, "West---Ouest.csv". There is REST service the provides English part of the file name. However, it does not provide French. So what I like to do is use the English part and replace the french part with say asterisk. So, the value for filename parameter would be - "West---*".  I tested asterisk, but seems that pathforresource does not work with that. Any work around to this problem?

Edit: English part is unique, so there's no file with the same english name.

Comment: get all files and `filter` for `$0.hasPrefix("West")`

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. This is not a dynamically created file; you put it into your project by hand before building. Its name is absolutely known to you, and you must use its absolute name. Of course, you are free to *change* its name when you put it into your project. And if you have several files, you are free to *form* the name dynamically in code when your app runs — after all, `theFileName` can be created on the fly however you like. For example, in my app I have files called `image1.jpg`, `image2.jpg`, and so on, so I start with a number, form the name, and fetch the image.